# How to make one toggle turn off when the other turns on in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, togglebutton, unity-ui

I am making a 2d game in unity. I am using the UI toggle methods and wish to make one of those turn off when the other one is turned on. The method I have tried is doing the following code below (InfiniteMode and CampaignMode are the names of the two toggles):

```
if (InfiniteMode.isOn)
    {
        PlayInfinite();
        CampaignMode.onValueChanged.Invoke(false);
    }

    if (CampaignMode.isOn)
    {
        PlayCampaign();
        InfiniteMode.onValueChanged.Invoke(false);
    }
```

Any help for what I can do to achieve this would be great.

Comment: Have you tried to replace `InfiniteMode.onValueChanged.Invoke(false)` by `InfinteMode.isOn = false`?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand you want to have two `UI Toggles` which acts as a group, when one of them is on, the rest of the items are off. In order to do this you can use `Toggle Group` component from `Unity UI`. You can find more information on that here: [Toggle Group documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-ToggleGroup.html).

If you look at `Toggle` component there is a `Group` variable. If you create an empty `GameObject` inside your Canvas and add `Toggle Group` component to it and assign that `Toggle Group` object to all your `Toggle`'s which you want to be a part of that group
it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add listeners to your toggles like this:

```
[SerializeField]
private Toggle myToggleVar;

private void Start() {
    // UI event listeners
    myToggleVar.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { onToggleExec(); });
}

private void onToggleExec() {
    Debug.Log("Toggled!") //here you need to manipulate your other toggle
}
```